# In checkout page I have button to redirect customer to login and after that he comeback to checkout page but page cant see user is logged in

Tags: laravel, vue.js, e-commerce, vue-router

This are butons in vue.js template
    Problem is that a have to refresh page after customer  is logged in if I want to see v-if="isLoggedIn" button.  Without refresh I can see only   v-if="!isLoggedIn". How can I change $router.push

```
               <div v-if="!isLoggedIn">     
                    <button class="col-md-4  b-primary float-left" @click="login">Login</button>

               </div>

                </div>
                <div v-if="isLoggedIn">

                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input id="address" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="address" required>

                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <button class="col-md-4 btn btn-sm btn-success float-right" v-if="isLoggedIn" @click="placeOrder">Continue</button>
                </div>
```

This is my script part :
                                                  this.$router.push({name: 'login', params: {nextUrl: '/checkout?pid='+this.pid}})

Comment: Use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for global state and track logged in status there

Comment: you can pass some data in router push to ensure that it is loggedin user in your code. but it will not best option. yes best option is if you use vuex to store the authentication status.

Comment: // I found temporary solution                                                                                  <script>    created() { 
    this.$on('loggedIn', function (e) {
  if (localStorage.getItem('example.com.jwt') == null) {
   setTimeout(this.zez, 1000)
     }
    })                                                                                                          
   },  
  methods: {   
   zez() {
    this.isLoggedIn = "zez"
   }                                                                                          </script>

Comment: // Later if customer press  Continue button I check is he loggedin :)